# Using Google Visualization API, how to turn off tooltips for a single column?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

According to this reference http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html , `tooltip.trigger = 'none'` turns off tooltips on a chart.

How do you use this? `data.tooltips.trigger = 'none'`?

And, how do you turn off tooltips for a single column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you draw the chart pass it as a param:

```
chart.draw(data, {trigger:'none'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling tooltips for a single columns isn't possible.
But you can get a similar effect by adding `enableInteractivity: false` to the series.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27750959/965984) for an example.